# need to check the icon inside your apk (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

i have created an Android App using Eclipse. When i upload this app on Play Store, the same error has been shown again and again. Although I have also tried many solutions, this is still not uploaded. Kindly give me suggestions how to solve this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest there is a part containing the icon name

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon_name"
```

make sure you have the specific icon `icon_name.png` in you resource.

Comment: tnx for u re attention bro    ///////                                                                      in drawable or drawable-hdpi or drawable-ldpi ??

Comment: you can place different images in different folders.. or a single one in any of them .. for example i place a 72X72 icon in hdpi